# Floating Action Button is unclickable?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

The FAB had worked previously when i used a `FrameLayout`, however when i added the FAB xml code under a new `LinearLayout` and changed the parent layout to `RelativeLayout`, it doesn't seem to respond to my Clicks anymore.

Here's the xml...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/song_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="455dp"
    android:divider="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:scrollbarSize="20dp"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/custom_listview_scrollbar"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/library_footer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@layout/bg_player_footer"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_width="86dp"
        android:layout_height="86dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@drawable/player_bt"
        android:clickable="true" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here's the onClick method for the FAB...

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                ((FabListener) getActivity()).onFabSelected();

            }
        });
```

Any solutions? Thanks!

### EDIT

Nevermind. Android Studio's 2.0 Instant Run seemed to be the reason behind the issue. Just needed to do a full rebuild.

Comment: instant run works only on Layouts!!! we need to remember it when using it. Thanks

Comment: Where all instant run works and where all instant run doesn't work ? How to do full build without cleaning ?

Comment: @SomasundaramMahesh You can disable InstantRun, so that It work like normal. Read full details of  [Instant run](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/instant-run)

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a LinearLayout ? I don't think that it's necessary.

Try to remove this and add

```
android:clickable="true"
```

in the FloatingActionButton tag

Comment: The code works, it was just Android Studios buggy IDE that wasn't. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JamieSmith  Sofiane also correct, you dnt need LinerLayout there, put both ListView and fab in RelativeLayout.

Comment: I know, but the LinearLayout in my case acts as a separate Layout Element at the bottom of the ListView. And the FAB is placed on top of that element.

Comment: Ok ;) ! Another thing : fill_parent is deprecated, you should use match_parent

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to match_parent.